# template instantiation depth exceeds maximum - how to stop particular case?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I have a following function:

```
template<unsigned fromLine, unsigned toLine = fromLine>
void stateChanged()
{
    // onStateChangeHandler[fromLine]();

    if (fromLine < toLine)
        stateChanged<fromLine + 1, toLine>();
}
```

which I call it in a following way:

```
stateChanged<0>();
stateChanged<1>();
stateChanged<2>();
stateChanged<3>();
stateChanged<4>();
stateChanged<5, 9>();
stateChanged<10, 15>();
```

I am receiving fatal error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900.
I assumed in C++14 the if condition will stop it automatically. So, how to do this properly?

Comment: I believe you need `if constexpr`, because otherwise even if `fromLine >= toLine`, it still needs to instantiate `stateChanged<fromLine+1, toLine>` for that branch of the code.

Comment: Are you stuck in C++14, or can you use a later standard?

Comment: Are you stuck with C++14, or can you use C++17?

Comment: Unfortunately the compiler I use is up to C++14

Comment: Note that there are tags that you can use if you're constrained to a specific language revision. Make sure to use the c++ tag as well, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the ability to use `if constexpr` in the template definition, you need to change how you do the looping in order to introduce a way for the compiler to reach a terminal state and stop the template instantiation.

We can do this with a helper class that, rather than going from start to finish, processes a number of lines.

```
template <unsigned curLine, unsigned numLines>
void updateStateChanged()
{
    // onStateChangeHandler[curLine]();
    stateChanged<curLine + 1, numLines - 1>();
}

template <unsigned curLine>
void updateStateChanged<curLine, 0>()
{
    // onStateChangeHandler[curLine]();
}

// Then we can modify your original class to call this helper:

template<unsigned fromLine, unsigned toLine = fromLine>
void stateChanged()
{
    updateStateChanged(fromLine, toLine - fromLine);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `if constexpr` instead of `if` will prevent this code from *infinitely recurring*.

As your code is written now, **every** instantiation of `stateChanged` requests a different instantiation of `stateChanged`.

[before](https://godbolt.org/z/4YGKhY) [Compiler Explorer]

[after](https://godbolt.org/z/M16z3r) [Compiler Explorer]

```
template<unsigned fromLine, unsigned toLine = fromLine>
void stateChanged()
{
    // onStateChangeHandler[fromLine]();

    if constexpr(fromLine < toLine)
    {
        // If the above expression is false, this code is not compiled.
        stateChanged<fromLine + 1, toLine>();
    }
}
```

**Update**:

On C++14, the same effect can be produced with some SFINAE.

```
template<unsigned fromLine, unsigned toLine = fromLine,
         typename std::enable_if_t< fromLine>=toLine >* = nullptr >
void stateChanged()
{
    // onStateChangeHandler[fromLine]();
}

template<unsigned fromLine, unsigned toLine = fromLine,
         typename std::enable_if_t< fromLine<toLine >* = nullptr >
void stateChanged()
{
    // onStateChangeHandler[fromLine]();

    stateChanged<fromLine + 1, toLine>();
}
```

[C++14 after](https://godbolt.org/z/bcM7d9) [Compiler Explorer]

Comment: Unfortunately the `if constexpr` is not a part of c++14 standard.

Comment: @noonespecial thanks for catching that.  Updated.

Comment: doesnt compile for a following: stateChanged<0,5>();